# VerifySet and SetupSet giving exception for an Indexed Property

Tags: c#, automated-tests, moq

I am trying to verify call to an indexed property setter. The property is settable in the interface and is of type `byte[]`
This is my code for verifying the setter:

```
var valueBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TestPrivateDataSourceValue);
Mock.Get(privateDataSource).VerifySet(dataSource => dataSource[TestPrivateDataSourceIndex] = valueBytes, Times.Once());
```

But I am getting the following exception:
[image]

What could be going wrong? I retried this in a separate project, and there it is working fine.

Comment: *I retried this in a separate project, and there it is working fine* << does that mean you can't reproduce it?

Answer (score 1):

The `byte[]` type is a reference type. This means that when you're doing the verification, Moq is comparing the references and not the content of the arrays. If `valueBytes` is created again somewhere in the method you're testing, its reference would be different from the one you created for verification, even if their contents are identical. This is a very common issue with `byte[]` and Moq.

A workaround for this is to use `It.Is<byte[]>(b => b.SequenceEqual(valueBytes))` for the verification:

```
Mock.Get(privateDataSource).VerifySet(dataSource => dataSource[TestPrivateDataSourceIndex] = It.Is<byte[]>(b => b.SequenceEqual(valueBytes)), Times.Once());
```